# I need to search in Notepad++ for lines not ending with ','

Tags: regex, notepad++

for example:

```
text.log file:
123,
4312421
53423543,
5643645,
```

Will only return/replace the 4312421 with 4312421,

I need to fix many files that are old and not ending with ','

at the end of some lines.

Answer (score 3):

Replace using a lookbehind in regex mode:

**Find:**

```
(?<!,)$
```

**Replace:**

```
, [just a single comma]
```